# php OOP call to a method in a class outside the current class

Tags: php, oop

Is there a way to call a method in a class outside of the current class?  For an example:

```
class firstclass
{
    function method1()
    {
       return "foo";
    }
}
class secondclass
{
    function method2()
    {
        $myvar = firstclass::method1;
        return $myvar;
    }
}
```

Where the `$myvar = firstclass::method1;` is an attempt to access the firstclass method1.
The desired result in this example would be  `$myvar = "foo"`.

I know I could use "extend", but wanted to know if there was a way to do it without "extend"?

Comment: What do you intend to do? Are you using PHP 4 or 5? If you're using PHP 5 you should declare your methods `static` if you intend to use them statically.

Comment: @BoltClock, Right... This is just an example.  I will be using static or public for the methods.

Comment: Yeah it wasn't clear at first since the code example is valid PHP 4 (other than your method call).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `method1` is a static method, you just need parentheses. It's just like a normal function call.

```
$myvar = firstclass::method1();
```

Incidentally, if you don't do anything else with `$myvar` other than returning it, you can shorten your method into one line of code:

```
return firstclass::method1();
```

The purpose of the `extends` keyword is for when you want `secondclass` to inherit the properties and methods of `firstclass`. In other words, you establish a parent-child relationship between the two classes. If they're not related at all, then you should not declare `secondclass extends firstclass`. You can still make use of either class in the scope of other classes by simply referencing their class names.

Answer (score 1):

Add `()` in the method call

```
function method2()
    {
        $myvar = firstclass::method1();
        return $myvar;
    }
```

OR

```
function method2()
        {
            $firstObj= new firstclass();
            $myvar = $firstObj->method1();
            return $myvar;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks... I can't believe I missed them.

Answer (score 1):

```
class firstclass
{
    public static function method1()
    {
       return "foo";
    }
}
class secondclass
{
    public function method2()
    {
        $myvar = firstclass::method1();
        return $myvar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your source code is not a good example of object oriented programming at all**.

You **SHOULD** always pass `firstclass` into a `secondclass` using for example constructor. Then you can call `first class` from inside the `secondclass`.

## Object injection

```
class firstclass
{
    function method1()
    {
        return "foo";
    }
}

class secondclass
{
    /**
     * @var firstclass
     */
    private $firstClass;

    /**
     * @param firstclass $firstClass
     */
    public function __construct(firstclass $firstClass)
    {
        $this->firstClass = $firstClass;
    }

    function method2()
    {
        return $this->firstClass->method1();
    }
}

print_r((new secondclass(new firstclass))->method2());
```

## Callable injection

If you don't want use the whole instance of `firstclass` inject callable inside the `secondclass` and then call it.

#### Calling method instance

```
class firstclass
{
    function method1()
    {
        return "foo";
    }
}

class secondclass
{
    /**
     * @var callable
     */
    private $method1;

    /**
     * @param callable $method1
     */
    public function __construct(callable $method1)
    {
        $this->method1 = $method1;
    }

    function method2()
    {
        return call_user_func($this->method1);
    }
}

print_r((new secondclass(array(new firstclass, 'method1')))->method2());
```

#### Calling static method

```
class firstclass
{
    static function method1()
    {
        return "foo";
    }
}

print_r((new secondclass('firstclass::method1'))->method2());
```